# Set output DC operating point of Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to set the output DC operating point to 2.5 V. Here is my schematic showing DC operating point.
[image: Schematic showing DC operating point]

If I replace the opamp with ideal opamp, the output DC operating point is set as 2.5V. With the real world device, I am unable to set the DC operating point.

Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: Step 1: Never let an active low shutdown pin float. Pull it up.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I did it. Doesn't help! As per the datasheet it can be left floating or high to enable the amp.

Comment: That schematic does not include the input bias currents (current sources on pins 3 and 4 of the op amp).   The DC resistance on the (+) input  pin is 21k ohms, and that on the (-) pin is 300k ohms, and the bias current creates a voltage offset because those values are different.  Match and/or minimize input resistances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The differential voltage across the input terminals of your opamp is way too high to be in regulation. The output is clipping the negative rail trying to sink the 10 uA of input bias current through R1. Try using smaller resistors for R1,R2,R3.

Comment: I am modelling a signal source, apparently it has 300k of source resistance, so I can't do away with R1. I am having R2 equal to 300k to have max power transfer.

Comment: @Ash you are not listening. You can't use this opamp with 300 kohm feedback resistance because the device input bias current is nominally 10 uA and possibly as bad as 40 uA. Read the data sheet and think again. You might also consider accepting a few answers to questions you've raised. These things do get spotted and people will be less inclined to help if you don't pay this very reasonable fee.

Comment: The LTC6200 is a bjt based opamp, typically with high-resistance sources you tend to go for a cmos opamp. Also with the 300k feedback resistor forms a pole with capacitance hanging off the inverting terminal (stray capacitance on board and parasitic to the opamp itself), so if you did build it this way there is a good chance it will oscillate.

Comment: Sorry Andy, I got the point now. I will be mindful of this from now onward.

Answer (score 0):

What do you man by unable to set the operating point?

That opamp has an input bias current of about 10uA ([LT6200 datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/62001ff.pdf))

Why use that opamp? - it is a fairly exotic high bandwidth one.  It has very low noise but if you wanted that you should be be using much lower resistance values.

Comment: Since my input common mode signal level is at 2.7, the output should be set to 2.7 V, instead it is ~148mV. I need to invert signals upto a frequency of 10 MHz, so need a high gain bandwidth product OpAMP

Comment: What are the voltages at the two input pins?

Answer (score 0):

Your schematic shows no VDD bypass cap. Add one right across the VDD/GND pins, with at most 1mm leads. Of value 0.01uF, SMT.Add 1 Ohm resistor between that Cbypass and some remote cap, of value 10uF. The 1 Ohm is to dampen and prevent ringing of that CLC network.

You need a ground-plane, to minimize the feedback from output back to input.
You have 4 ""GND" nodes, With the bypass cap, there are 5. Use a 3" by 3" GND PLANE.

What is the bandwidth of the SCOPE you've used to characterize the Opamp output voltage? The OpAmp may be oscillating.

Comment: We're talking about simulations here.